# How to print hex numbers to a file?

Tags: c, file-io, hex

I am trying to store every hex value from 0000 to fffe into a file.  How would I use fwrite or fprintf to place these values into a file?

At the moment, I have a while loop that prints all the numbers using printf (which is to the console screen), but I need them in a file.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to print `0000 0001 0002...` or to output the following hexadecimal values: `0x00 0X00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x02 ...` ?

Comment: Have you tried using fopen()?

Comment: Have you looked to see how this is done?  I got a ton of results just Googleing "write to a file in C".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fprintf(fp, "%04x", your_number)
```