# Saving Hex output from sprintf into a File in C

Tags: c, hex

I am having a problem saving a hex output from sprintf into a File. I need to save the hex outputted by sprintf in actual hex format instead of ASCII. When I try to do so, the characters are stored in ASCII as shown in the image below.

[image]

The Last four characters in the file are outputted by sprintf. I need these characters to be displayed as 00 00 00 0A in the Hex view instead of the ASCII View

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138065/how-to-print-hex-numbers-to-a-file?rq=1

Comment: Read a [`printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: The output for the fprintf is also saved as ASCII not actual Hex

Comment: You should show some code. Like, what does "actual hex format" mean? When talking about "hexadecimal numbers", it implicitly means ASCII. Perhaps you mean, "as raw binary data"? But then how does `sprintf` relate to that, do you need to *parse* `sprintf` output back to raw bytes? Showing some code would be easiest way to clarify the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a number itself instead of its string representation to a file, you should use `fwrite()`, do something like

```
int i = 10;
fwrite(&i, sizeof(i), 1, fp);
```

See [`fwrite(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) for further details.